# Syntax Error in writing an integer into a file in python

Tags: python, file, syntax-error

I am trying to get a list of words and their frequency from one text file and trying to write the distinct words and their frequency count into another file.
my code is

```
import sys

f = open (sys.argv[1])

l = []
a = []

def store(f) :
    for x in f :
        y = x.split()
        for e in y :
            if e in l :
                k=l.index(e)
                a[k]=a[k]+1
            else :
                a.append(1)
                l.append(e)

    return

store(f)
f.close()

f1 = open (sys.argv[2],"w+") 

for i1 in range(0,len(l)) :
    f1.write(l[i1])
    f1.write((str)a[i1])

f1.close()
```

But I am facing an error and I cannot figure out why, what I realized that I needed to typecast a[i1] to string type, but that does not resolve the issue.

ERROR is :

```
python 5b.py test.txt new.txt
  File "5b.py", line 28
    f1.write((str)a[i1])
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: should be str(a[i1])

Answer (score 0):

Its syntax error should be like this

```
f1.write(str(a[i1]))
```

Comment: I think this should be in comment rather than in answer.

Comment: can I know how can you break a line

Comment: also, can I know the exact reason why do we need to typecast?

Comment: file write need to be in a string  such as  TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Comment: what do you mean by the break into a line? read line by line is that it?